# Allowing apostrophe in username and email address WSO2 Identity Server [5.8.0]

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a WSO2 Identity Server 5.8.0 currently setup and running. By default it looks like the apostrophe isn’t acceptable in the username or email address for the user.

Three  places give me errors with the current configuration:

1. In the Home > Add New User:  I get a “Username pattern policy
   violated”
2. In the Home > Update Profile: I get a “Email is not valid”
3. In the API to POST: api/identity/user/v1.0/validate-username I get Invalid = 60002

Where do I change the setting to allow apostrophe in username and email address?

Looking in documentation it seems like I should be able to change the User Store > Username Regex but when changed I get “Error occurred while updating user stories”
Also checked Identity > Claims > List but it seems strange to update the claim regex?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apostrophe is not supported by default and need to change the username regex to allow that. For IS 5.8 and older versions, we need to change the following regex props in `/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml`

1.

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">{Regex}</Property>
```

- To change the regular expression to validate usernames (In BE). By default, strings having a length of 5 to 30 between non-empty characters are allowed.

2. 

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">{Regex}</Property>
```

- To change the regular expression used by the front-end components for username validation.

You can find the WSO2 recommendation for username regex here https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/usernames-in-identity-server/#best-practices-for-username-creation